# Duplicate rows according to a condition with explode and array

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My idea is to count the number of open deliveries at month end. Here is my dataframe `df`.  (SOD: Start of Delivery, EOD/ End of Delivery) :

```
Reference   Start Date   StartTimestamp  EndDate     EndTimestamp        
1           2/15/2019    SOD             4/18/2019   EOD                                       
2           2/16/2019    SOD             2/23/2019   EOD                                        
3           2/17/2019    SOD             3/4/2019    EOD                                        
4           3/1/2019     SOD             Null        Null  



from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, explode
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    df1 = df.withColumn("EndOfTheMonth", F.lastday("Start Date"))
            .withColumn("IsDeliveryOpen", when((col("Start Date") <= col("EndOfTheMonth")) & ((col("EndDate") >= col("EndOfTheMonth")) | 
(col("EndTask").isNull())),1).otherwise(0))
```

To do this, I would like to duplicate rows in a new dataframe for each month when the `End Date` of the delivery is higher than the `EndOfTheMonth'.

I try do this by using `explode`but I don't know how to use this function :

```
df2 = (df1.filter(col("IsDeliveryOpen") == 1)
         .select("Reference").explode()
         .withColumn("EndOfTheMonth", F.add_months(lastday("StartDate"), 1))
```

Desired Output is to be able to `groupBy` per `EndOfTheMonth`:

```
Reference   Start Date   StartTimestamp  EndDate     EndTimestamp EndOfTheMonth IsDeliveryOpen      
1           8/15/2019    SOD             9/18/2019   EOD          8/31/2019     1
1           8/15/2019    SOD             9/18/2019   EOD          9/30/2019     0
2           8/16/2019    SOD             8/23/2019   EOD          8/31/2019     0                         
3           6/17/2019    SOD             8/4/2019    EOD          6/30/2019     1
3           6/17/2019    SOD             8/4/2019    EOD          7/31/2019     1
3           6/17/2019    SOD             8/4/2019    EOD          8/31/2019     0
4           8/1/2019     SOD             Null        Null         8/31/2019     1
4           8/1/2019     SOD             Null        Null         9/30/2019     1
```

Comment: what is your spark version? 2.4.0+ or below

Comment: I assume it is the last version. I am using pyspark with Azure databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Spark 2.4.0+**, you can use **[sequence](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#sequence)** + **[transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform)** + explode to create new Rows with this task:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df_new = (df
    .withColumn('s_date', expr("last_day(to_date(StartDate, 'M/d/yyyy'))"))
    .withColumn('e_date', expr("last_day(IFNULL(to_date(EndDate, 'M/d/yyyy'), add_months(current_date(),-1)))"))
    .withColumn('EndOfTheMonth', expr('''
          explode_outer(transform(
            sequence(0, int(months_between(e_date, s_date))), i -> add_months(s_date,i)
          ))
     '''))
    .withColumn('IsDeliveryOpen', expr("IF(e_date > EndOfTheMonth or EndDate is Null, 1, 0)"))
)

df_new.show()
+---------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|Reference|StartDate|StartTimestamp|  EndDate|EndTimestamp|    s_date|    e_date|EndOfTheMonth|IsDeliveryOpen|
+---------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
|        1|8/15/2019|           SOD|9/18/2019|         EOD|2019-08-31|2019-09-30|   2019-08-31|             1|
|        1|8/15/2019|           SOD|9/18/2019|         EOD|2019-08-31|2019-09-30|   2019-09-30|             0|
|        2|8/16/2019|           SOD|8/23/2019|         EOD|2019-08-31|2019-08-31|   2019-08-31|             0|
|        3|6/17/2019|           SOD| 8/4/2019|         EOD|2019-06-30|2019-08-31|   2019-06-30|             1|
|        3|6/17/2019|           SOD| 8/4/2019|         EOD|2019-06-30|2019-08-31|   2019-07-31|             1|
|        3|6/17/2019|           SOD| 8/4/2019|         EOD|2019-06-30|2019-08-31|   2019-08-31|             0|
|        4| 8/1/2019|           SOD|     null|        null|2019-08-31|2019-09-30|   2019-08-31|             1|
|        4| 8/1/2019|           SOD|     null|        null|2019-08-31|2019-09-30|   2019-09-30|             1|
+---------+---------+--------------+---------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+--------------+

df_new = df_new.drop('s_date', 'e_date')
```

**How does it work:**

1. convert *StartDate*, *EndDate* to DateType with the value to the last_day of the same month(*s_date*, *e_date*). if *EndDate* is NULL, then set its value to last_day of the previous month from the current_date
2. calculate *# of months* between the above two dates and then create a sequence(0, #months) and transform it into an array of months(`EndOfTheMonth`) between StartDate and EndDate (inclusively)
3. use explode_outer to generate Rows for all months in the above array
4. calculate the IsDeliveryOpen flag accordingly. I removed `StartDate <= EndOfTheMonth` in your code since it's always true based on how *EndOfTheMonth* is calculated.

**Note:** the above can also be written as one SQL statement:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('t_df')

spark.sql('''

    WITH d AS (
        SELECT *
             , last_day(to_date(StartDate, 'M/d/yyyy')) as s_date
             , last_day(IFNULL(to_date(EndDate, 'M/d/yyyy'),add_months(current_date(),-1))) as e_date
        FROM t_df
    )
    SELECT d.*
         , m.EndOfTheMonth
         , IF(e_date > m.EndOfTheMonth or d.EndDate is NULL,1,0) AS IsDeliveryOpen
    FROM d
    LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode(
        transform(sequence(0, int(months_between(e_date, s_date))), i -> add_months(s_date,i))
    ) m AS EndOfTheMonth

''').show()
```

### Update on weekly ranges:

Per your comments, to do the same on the weekly basis, you can adjust `s_date` and `e_date` to be the Monday of the same week using `date_trunc('WEEK', date_col)` and then use `sequence()` function to generate an array of dates between *s_date* and *end_date* with 7 days interval, see below code:

```
df_weekly = (df
    .withColumn('s_date', expr("date(date_trunc('WEEK', to_date(StartDate, 'M/d/yyyy')))"))
    .withColumn('e_date', expr("date(date_trunc('WEEK', IFNULL(to_date(EndDate, 'M/d/yyyy'), date_sub(current_date(),7))))"))
    .withColumn('StartOfTheWeek', expr('explode_outer(sequence(s_date, e_date, interval 7 days))'))
    .withColumn('IsDeliveryOpen', expr("IF(e_date > StartOfTheWeek or EndDate is Null, 1, 0)"))
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @jxc that has solved my problem and enables me to move forward.
I just had to remove the duplicates to get accurate results.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to duplicate the same logic to get the result at a weekly basis ? That is really difficult for my point of view.

Comment: @MathildeP, check the last section "Update on weekly ranges"